# Android: Custom Listview item - force on one line

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom cell for my listview which has TEXT    NUMBER - which works fine, however when the TEXT goes over one line, the right hand number goes over more than one line too which looks silly. Is there a property to fix this from happening?

[image]

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="[21]"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `layout_weight` for views is not kicking-in. For that, I think you are missing to define `android:weightSum="10"` within your `LinearLayout` definition. Moreover, you need to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` to both of your `TextView`.

Comment: You little ripper, thanks a lot for that - Works perfectly now :)

Comment: In addition, I would suggest you to set `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:ellipsize="marquee"` to your `TextView` called **txtOption**. I think it will make it look good for overflown texts.